# How to remove non-ASCII characters from a string in bat script?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

Sometimes the `%COMPUTERNAME%` variable value contains non-ASCII characters, but when I use this variable in a batch script, I need to keep only the ASCII characters of the correlated value.

How could I go about getting a string value with non-ASCII characters to only display the ASCII characters using a batch script?

Comment: Might be a good choice to first change chars with diacritics (acccents) to their base character [see this PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7840951/6811411)

Answer (score 2):

You can use some of the methods as listed on [Remove special characters from a string using Regular Expression (Regex)](http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2015/08/powershell-remove-special-characters.html) with a batch script as the one below for example.

Just use the native power of Windows as designed by [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com) and get this job done simply by using PowerShell in your batch script to set the `%computername%` without the non-ASCII character for what's returned with the PowerShell commands.

---

### **Batch Script to Remove Non-Ascii**

*Be sure to set the `SET PCName=` variable accordingly in your script to incorporate with however your logic already works (e.g. `SET PCName=%computername%`, etc.)*

*Rather than using the `DO ECHO %%~F` with the `FOR /F` loop in the below script, you could set that to `DO SET PCNameASCII=%%~F` instead for example and then the `%PCNameASCII%` variable can be incorporated into the rest of your batch script logic accordingly and that'd always be the `%ComputerName%` variable value but only the ASCII characters.*

```
@ECHO ON

SET PCName=Laäff¥yTaäffi¡

SET PSScript=%Temp%\~tmpRemovenonascii.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"

ECHO $String = '%PCName%'                                             >>"%PSScript%"
ECHO $String = $String -replace '[^^\x30-\x39\x41-\x5A\x61-\x7A]+', ''>>"%PSScript%"
ECHO ECHO $String                                                     >>"%PSScript%"

SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"') DO ECHO %%~F

PAUSE

GOTO EOF
```

*See the **Further Resources** section and the notes therein for other methods using Regex to remove special characters, etc.*

---

> **Before (non-ascii)**
>
> ```
> LaõffÑyTaõffií
> ```
>
> **After (results)**
>
> ```
> LaffyTaffi
> ```

---

### Further Resources

- [Replace()](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)
- [FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [Remove special characters from a string using Regular Expression (Regex)](http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2015/08/powershell-remove-special-characters.html)
- > ```
  > # Regular Expression - Using the \W (opposite of \w) 
  > $String -replace '[\W]', ''
  >
  > # Regular Expression - Using characters from a-z, A-Z, 0-9 
  > $String -replace '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ''
  >
  > # Regular Expression - Using ASCII 
  > $String -replace '[^\x30-\x39\x41-\x5A\x61-\x7A]+', ''
  >
  > # Regular Expression - Unicode - Matching Specific Code Points 
  > $String -replace '[^\u0030-\u0039\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A]+', ''
  >
  > # Regular Expression - Unicode - Unicode Categories 
  > $String -replace '[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]', ''
  >
  > # Regular Expression - Unicode - Unicode Categories
  > #  Exceptions: We want to keep the following characters: ( } _ 
  > $String -replace '[^\p{L}\p{Nd}/(/}/_]', ''
  > ```

Comment: I'd use `$Env:COMPUTERNAME` in the PowerShell part to not involve the current code page conversion

Comment: I thought about putting that but since it was mentioned that the `%computername%` variable was already being used, I just left that as is since that's what is already being used to keep as much of it non-PowerShell as possible to ensure the OP can easily incorporate it into the existing logic being used on their side. But yes, using `$String = $Env:COMPUTERNAME` in PowerShell would give the same result as `$String = '%PCName%'` does from the batch script I provided.